# Reverse Start With

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have an organization table that looks like this:

```
 USER_ID | USER_NAME | RPT_TO_USR
 1         Bob         2
 2         John        3
 3         Wendy       {null}
```

I'm trying to build a query that will build my organization and identify the different levels. I was able to do this if I have a specific user I want to start with via `CONNECT BY`

```
SELECT USER_ID, USER_NAME, RPT_TO_USR, LEVEL
FROM USERTABLE
START WITH USER_ID = 1
CONNECT BY USER_ID = PRIOR RPT_TO_USR
```

However I want to start with user 3 and build down. I've been reviewing the Oracle documentation and some CTE post on Stack Overflow trying to see if that would be a solution, or if there was a way to reverse the flow of the `START WITH` `CONNECT BY`, but so far I haven't had any success.

Basically instead of starting with Bob and knowing he reports to John who reports to Wendy I want to start with Wendy and know that John reports to her and Bob reports to John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive query with CTE:

```
WITH CTE (USER_ID,USER_NAME,RPT_TO_USR,LV) AS
(
    SELECT USER_ID,USER_NAME,RPT_TO_USR,1 
      FROM USERTABLE 
     WHERE RPT_TO_USR IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.USER_ID,A.USER_NAME,A.RPT_TO_USR,B.LV + 1
      FROM USERTABLE A, CTE B
     WHERE A.RPT_TO_USR = B.USER_ID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great example to, and I end up with more than just a level with the way you used RPT_TO_USR appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

should just be a   matter of changing the column you're using... to start with and order of the two columns in the connect by XXX = prior...

```
SELECT USER_ID, USER_NAME, RPT_TO_USR, LEVEL
from org
start with rpt_to_usr is null
CONNECT BY RPT_TO_USR = PRIOR USER_ID
```

[image]

Comment: I had unrightfully assumed I wouldn't be able to use nulls in this instance for some reason. Thanks for pointing out the error in my thinking.

Comment: This is actually one of the more common uses of hierarchical queries starting at the root of the tree and traversing out to the leaf nodes.  Switching it, starting with Bob simply yields the path from Bob back to his highest level manager.  It's useful information but hardly interesting.